# Couldn't join two tables on Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am a beginner of spring boot application. I want to join the course table and the student table together. What I tried so far I attached code below. I didn't get any errors. When the student page is loaded I show course id only I need to display the name instead of the id. I attached the screenshot image below.
[image]

Above screenshot image only displayed the course id I need to display the course name.

**Student Controller**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewStudentPage(Model model) {
     List<Student> liststudent = services.listAll();
     model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);
     System.out.print("Get / ");    
     return "Student";
}
```

I made the relation the below. What I tried so far now.

**Course.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Course {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String coursename;
    private int duration;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    public Course()
    {       
        
    }
 
    public Course(Long id, String coursename, int duration) {
        
        this.id = id;
        this.coursename = coursename;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCoursename() {
        return coursename;
    }
    public void setCoursename(String coursename) {
        this.coursename = coursename;
    }
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", coursename=" + coursename + ", duration=" + duration + "]";
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String stname;
    private int course;
    private int fee;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<Student> student;

    public Student() {
        
        
    }
   
    public Student(Long id, String stname, int course, int fee) {
    
        this.id = id;
        this.stname = stname;
        this.course = course;
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getStname() {
        return stname;
    }
    public void setStname(String stname) {
        this.stname = stname;
    }
    public int getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(int course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public int getFee() {
        return fee;
    }
    public void setFee(int fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", stname=" + stname + ", course=" + course + ", fee=" + fee + "]";
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository**

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{ }
```

**Student.html**

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
             <th>Fee</th>
             <th>edit</th>
             <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr  th:each="student : ${liststudent}">
        <td th:text="${student.id}">Student ID</td>
        <td th:text="${student.stname}">Student Name</td>
        <td th:text="${student.course}">Course</td>
         <td th:text="${student.fee}">Fee</td>
        <td>
            <a th:href="@{'/Student/edit/' + ${student.id}}">Edit</a>
        </td>                               
        <td>
            <a th:href="@{'/Student/delete/' + ${student.id}}">Delete</a>
        </td>           
        </tr> 
   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Custom Code i wrote it to Join

@Repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{

    @Query(value="select student.id, student.stname, course.coursename from student Inner JOIN course ON  student.course= course.id", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Object[]> findStudent();
    
    
}
```

Comment: What do you think `${student.course}` prints.

Comment: ya. student table has a colum  course. here displayed course id.

Comment: ${student.course} i want print here instead of course id course name want to print

Comment: No it doesn't. Forget about the database... It is your object model that is important here. What does `getCourse` return from `Student`. Now what does your `Course` `toString` method looks like. If you want to print the course name you should get the name from the `Course`. Now that has a `getName` method, how would you express that with `${student.course}` (if this returns the `Course` object?).

Comment: i modified above full code of  course and student entity.getCourse

Comment: i add the full code sir how to make relationship what are the changes need to be done

Comment: You suddenly changed your mapping with how it was. First the `Student` had a `Course` now it suddenly is an `int`.

Comment: yes sir.because when the student register the course. i listed the couse using dropdown list. when i selected course and add the record instead of course name id should save in the database table.so i that i changed as course as int

Comment: I strongly suggest you read on how JPA works instead of randomly change things. Revert that change back so that `Student` has a `Course` (the `Student` having a List of `Student`s doesn't make sense, that should be part of the `Course`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234767/discussion-between-gowry-kanth-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a custom query to get the course name. Your listAll() return all student object without course, the payload doesn't have any variable like name and you have `course id` in your entity that's why `ID` appearing in your UI.

Your student object have course objects also you can get like below.

**you have the wrong relationship on your entity correct as below.**
**It should come under  ManyToMany relationship because one user have many courses and one course belong to many student anyway you started as oneToMany then follow as below.**

within Student Entity.

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Course> course;
```

within Course entity

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Student student;
```

then try you access the course object as below.

```
th:field="*{student.course.name}"
```

if you want to try a custom query then try to as below.

```
@Query(value="select s.id, s.name, c.name from Student s left JOIN Course c on student.course_id= c.id", nativeQuery=true)
List<Object[]> findStudent();
```

Comment: how to write the code for this on StudentRepository

Comment: Can you try as above.

Comment: ya ran it i got the error HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Comment: Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{ } here how to join

Comment: check answer now

Comment: ya sir i did what u said now i just the code i got the error of Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource com.example.studentmanagement.Domain.Course column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: In your student object you have, private int course; is that join coloum?

Comment: What field you are using in course table for joining purpose?

Comment: custom code i tried i attached above what i tried but when i load the student table HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Comment: https://github.com/raguram1986/springproject full github link

Comment: Give sometimes I will check.

Comment: Add your dB script also then I can verify the  entity mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234772/discussion-between-gowry-kanth-and-selvakumar-anushan).